# Eclipse CDT and MinGW-w64: "update" MinGW-w64 for use with existing Eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64

I have several Eclipse C++ projects that use the MinGW-x64 version 6.3 just fine, but now I want to upgrade to a newer gcc compiler. I downloaded and installed the 7.3 version from MinGW-builds and I noticed that it installed in the C:\Program Files\mingw64 instead of C:\mingw64. So, now I have two MinGW-w64 installations on my workstation, but Eclipse still only recognizes the older one. How do I made Eclipse use the newer installation for my existing projects?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update the PATH environment variable.

[image]

From there, click "environment variables". Then (on the lower window tagged "System Variables"), click "Path" (so that it gets blued out). Click "Edit". Then click in the path to your previous MinGW location (something like " C:\mingw64\bin"). Select it, and click "Browse". Then, (start in "C:" and) go through the system file to your new MinGW-w64 location (e.g: "C:\Program Files\mingw64"), click in it, then go to the 'bin' folder location. Click in it. Then, "Ok". That's it!

By then, you will have uploaded your path variable to the new location.

P.S. - If you already know the full path to the bin location of the new MinGW version, you can simply delete the path to the old one (after clicking "Edit" in the system path vairables), and add the "new" path by simply pasting it (after clicking "new").